# Обособление обстоятельств

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли обособлять обстоятельства или, если это обстоятельства времени и образа действия, то обособление не требуется?

В рамках курса на политику импортозамещения (,) в новом 2015 году ООО «...» готово предложить  на отечественном рынке качественные шаровые краны российского производителя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, обособление не требуется, т.к. нет уточнения или причинного, а также уступительного значения

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, обособление здесь не требуется, но в словосочетании "в новом, 2015 году" надо поставить запятую, ибо второе определение носит здесь пояснительный характер. Иначе получается, что есть еще и "старый 2015 год"